# How can I from a low-pass filter function (firrrcos or rcosdesign) create a high-pass filter? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, bandpass-filter

I have to apply a bandpass filter on my sin signal. The filter I have to use is firrcos or rcosdesign (Matlab). Even if it's supposed to be a bandpass filter, it appears to work as a lowpass. Is there a solution to turn this lowpass into a highpass et use both to filter my signal?

Thanks.